# Excel: Return the latest date for each value in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel spreadsheet, I have a customer ID (Column A) and multiple purchase dates (Column B) for each customer. It looks something like this:

```
CustomerID   Purchase Date
1               1/1/20
1               1/6/20
1               1/18/20
2               1/15/20
2               1/26/20
3               1/14/20
3               1/7/20
3               1/28/20
4               2/5/20
5               1/16/20
5               1/9/20
...
```

What I would like to do: Find a formula to put in Column C that will tell me if the purchase date is the *largest / latest* for each customer ID. I am looking to create something that looks like this:

```
CustomerID   Purchase Date    FORMULA
1               1/1/20           NO
1               1/6/20           NO
1               1/18/20          YES
2               1/15/20          NO
2               1/26/20          YES
3               1/14/20          NO
3               1/7/20           NO
3               1/28/20          YES
4               2/5/20           YES
5               1/16/20          YES
5               1/9/20           NO
...
```

The end goal is to only keep the latest records for each customer (I could then simply delete all of the rows with 'NO'). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel/O365 or Excel 2019 you can use `MAXIFS`

```
 C2: =IF(B2=MAXIFS($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12,$A2),"YES","NO")
```

[image]

But if what you really want is ***keep the latest records for each customer***, then you might try using `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+.

And when your original table changes, merely **refresh** the query to return the current "latest dates".

All you need to do is **Group** by `Customer` with a `Max` operation on the `Date` Column.

[image]

**Results**

[image]

The above can all be done from the UI, but here is the

**M-Code**

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"CustomerID", Int64.Type}, {"Purchase Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"CustomerID"}, {{"Last Date", each List.Max([Purchase Date]), type date}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Answer (score 1):

*This issue can be solved by using an Array (CSE) formula:*

[image]

- Formula in cell `C31`:

  ```
  {=IF(MAX(INDEX((A31=$A$31:$A$41)*$B$31:$B$41,))=B31,"Yes","No")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill it down.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Option without CSE:

```
=IF(AGGREGATE(14,6,(A2=$A$2:$A$12)*($B$2:$B$12),1)=B2,"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is much easier than a formula and that is to use the sort function twice then delete duplicates.  The key is to sort by date with the newest date first; THEN sort by Customer ID (any order); THEN Delete Duplicates based on Customer ID.